# Specific page won't load in WebDriver

Tags: java, hash, webdriver

I'm getting this result in my Assert from the method isLoaded()

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<"[Problem loading page]"> but was:<"[Admin - Beleza na web]">
```

I think it maybe related with the fact that the url contains a hash, but i'm not sure.

URL exemple: http://page.com/#/signin

```
protected String title = "Admin - Beleza na web";

@Override
public void load() {
 driver.get(url);
}

@Override
public void isLoaded() {
 assertThat(title).isEqualTo(driver.getTitle());
}
```

Comment: Why is expected title `Problem loading page`?

Comment: I'm not expecting this title. I Expected the title `Admin - Beleza na web`, but I get `Problem loading page`. I'm updating my code with the value of the string `title`.

Comment: first change the order of assert to be correct: assertThat(driver.getTitle()).isEqualTo(title);

Comment: Second, make sure that the page is loading properly. Try using WebDriverWait to ensure that the title is presented before catching it